# Site loading more slowly when using www.site.mydomain.com than when using site.mydomain.com

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, web-hosting

I am hosting a site on my raspberry pi using Nginx and Raspbian (Debian Wheezy) and i am encountering a problem.

When i visit my site using :

```
site.mydomain.com
```

the sites load normally and fairly quickly but when i use :

```
www.site.mydomain.com
```

the site loads very slowly and even fails to load certain parts (for example the css)

I've tried looking at my Nginx sites-available file but nothing seemed wrong.

```
server {
    listen   80; 

    root /home/user/websites/www/site.mydomain.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.site.mydomain.com site.mydomain.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            deny all;
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

What steps could i do to try to identify where the problem is ?

```
dig www.anthony.lethuillier.net
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 13809
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 9

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.anthony.lethuillier.net. 3447 IN    A   89.158.171.35
www.anthony.lethuillier.net. 3447 IN    A   89.158.216.154
www.anthony.lethuillier.net. 3447 IN    A   85.69.0.191

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
lethuillier.net.    73246   IN  NS  ns-fr.1and1-dns.org.
lethuillier.net.    73246   IN  NS  ns-fr.1and1-dns.com.
lethuillier.net.    73246   IN  NS  ns-fr.1and1-dns.fr.
lethuillier.net.    73246   IN  NS  ns-fr.1and1-dns.biz.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns-fr.1and1-dns.fr. 51009   IN  A   217.160.80.4
ns-fr.1and1-dns.fr. 51009   IN  AAAA    2001:8d8:fe:53:0:d9a0:5004:100
ns-fr.1and1-dns.biz.    51009   IN  A   217.160.81.4
ns-fr.1and1-dns.biz.    51009   IN  AAAA    2001:8d8:fe:53:0:d9a0:5104:100
ns-fr.1and1-dns.com.    51009   IN  A   217.160.82.4
ns-fr.1and1-dns.com.    51009   IN  AAAA    2001:8d8:fe:53:0:d9a0:5204:100
ns-fr.1and1-dns.org.    51009   IN  A   217.160.83.4
ns-fr.1and1-dns.org.    51009   IN  AAAA    2001:8d8:fe:53:0:d9a0:5304:100
```

and

```
:dig anthony.lethuillier.net
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 46597
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 9

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; ANSWER SECTION:
anthony.lethuillier.net. 3307   IN  A   89.158.216.154

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
lethuillier.net.    73139   IN  NS  ns-fr.1and1-dns.org.
lethuillier.net.    73139   IN  NS  ns-fr.1and1-dns.fr.
lethuillier.net.    73139   IN  NS  ns-fr.1and1-dns.com.
lethuillier.net.    73139   IN  NS  ns-fr.1and1-dns.biz.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns-fr.1and1-dns.fr. 50902   IN  A   217.160.80.4
ns-fr.1and1-dns.fr. 50902   IN  AAAA    2001:8d8:fe:53:0:d9a0:5004:100
ns-fr.1and1-dns.biz.    50902   IN  A   217.160.81.4
ns-fr.1and1-dns.biz.    50902   IN  AAAA    2001:8d8:fe:53:0:d9a0:5104:100
ns-fr.1and1-dns.com.    50902   IN  A   217.160.82.4
ns-fr.1and1-dns.com.    50902   IN  AAAA    2001:8d8:fe:53:0:d9a0:5204:100
ns-fr.1and1-dns.org.    50902   IN  A   217.160.83.4
ns-fr.1and1-dns.org.    50902   IN  AAAA    2001:8d8:fe:53:0:d9a0:5304:100
```

Comment: What DNS records do you have?

Comment: Is this the info you need ?

A: 89.158.216.154
MX: mx00.1and1.fr
MX: mx01.1and1.fr

Comment: No. I mean what DNS records do you have for `site.mydomain.com` and `www.site.mydomain.com`

Comment: Added the results of the dig command, hope it's what you want (sorry I am not very knowledgeable in networking)

Comment: You have 3 `A` records for `www.anthony.lethuillier.net` and my guess, two of them don't belong to your server. Browser chooses random one and probably wrong, after that it has to wait for connection timeout before trying next one. Remove unnecessary IPs from DNS

Comment: BTW, usually you should have `CNAME` record for `www.` See `dig www.stackoverflow.com` for example.